# Access multi-dimensional WrappedArray elements in Java using Spark SQL Row

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, geojson

I have the following schema:

```
geometry: struct (nullable = true)
    -- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
        -- element: array (containsNull = true)  
            -- element: array (containsNull = true)
                -- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

In Java, how can I access the double element with a Spark SQL row?

The furthest I can seem to get is: row.getStruct(0).getList(0).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scala this works, I leave it to you to translate it to java:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray


object Demo {

  case class MyStruct(coordinates:Array[Array[Array[Double]]])
  case class MyRow(struct:MyStruct)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Demo").setMaster("local[*]"))
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._

    val data = MyRow(MyStruct(Array(Array(Array(1.0)))))
    val df= sc.parallelize(Seq(data)).toDF()

    // get first entry (row)
    val row = df.collect()(0)

    val arr = row.getAs[Row](0).getAs[WrappedArray[WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Double]]]](0)

    //access an element
    val res = arr(0)(0)(0)

    println(res) // 1.0

  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not seeing anyway to get this line to work in Java:       val res = arr(0)(0)(0)

Comment: @MichaelJ.Perry `arr(0) ` means nothing more than getting the element at index 0, maybe this line works like this in Java: `arr.get(0).get(0).get(0)` ?

Comment: Finally got it working, had to do row.apply(0).apply(0).apply(0).doubleValue(). Thanks for the help!!

Comment: this gave me a `java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray` but I changed the WrappedArray's to `.map(row => { row.getAs[Row](0).getAs[Seq[Seq[Seq[Double]]]](0) })` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to avoid accessing row directly. You can:

```
df.selectExpr("geometry[0][0][0]")
```

or

```
df.select(col("geometry").getItem(0).getItem(0).getItem(0))
```

and use the result.